# How to recompile IL

Tags: c#

So I need to make a very simple change to a DLL file.

I have successfully exported the dll file to IL language with Reflector, and have found the change I need to make (its just changing a URL). So if I make the change in notepad and save it, well thats great & easy, but now I cannot figure out how to build it back into a DLL file. I have tried to export it to a C# project which works, but building it gives me so many errors.

VS doesn't want to open it since exporting to IL doesn't provide a project file.

Comment: Reflexil.net maybe

Comment: Supposedly JetBrains dotPeek can decompile dlls into VS projects. But not tried it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, works perfectly:
decompile: ildasm file.dll /out:file.il
edit using notepad
recompile: ilasm file.il /DLL /fold /nologo /noautoinherit

.. and of course you can use your favourite decompiler tool such as VS or dotpeek to view the code nicely, then find it in the dirty IL version to edit it.

Comment: So if I were to do this with an EXE, I would do `ildasm file.exe /out:file.il` for decompiling and `ilasm file.il /EXE /fold /nologo /noautoinherit` for recomping?

Answer (score 2):

Just like VisualStudio ships with ildasm, it also ships with [ilasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx(v=vs.110).aspx). So you should be able to do:

> ilasm /dll myapp.il

Comment: Yeah just tried that, problem is the dump of the dll produces 7 files (only one of which is a .il file), so I cannot find a way to import them all back into the single dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I used Telerik JustDecompile. from a DLL I can create my project (right click on the assembly / create project c#/vb or IL), I open with VS, I change and I recompile.

Test it !